# Get created time

Tags: python

To get the last modified time of a file in python, I do:

```
lastmodifiedTime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
```

How do I get the created time?

Comment: You don't.  Most filesystems do not store that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If* you are on Windows, then [`os.path.getctime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) is the file creation time. On other platforms that information is not stored and that function returns the last change time instead.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters Will that not give the change time give. Doc says: Return the metadata change time of a file, reported by os.stat().

Comment: @MoreThanFive: On *Windows* it's the creation time of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`os.path.getctime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get the creation time.